# Яндекс Карты Определение местоположения + Поиск организаций

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Нужно с помощью Api Яндекс Карт показать ближайшие кафе рядом с текущим местоположением пользователя. Карта сначала определяет местоположение, а потом быстро соскакивает на центр города, словно обнуляя результаты геоопределения

Пример взят частично из песочницы, там же и тестировался

```html
function init() {
    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.74, 37.58],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
           
        });
  
    geolocation.get({
        provider: 'browser',
        mapStateAutoApply: true
    }).then(function (result) {

        myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
    });
 
 
 
    // Создадим экземпляр элемента управления «поиск по карте»
    // с установленной опцией провайдера данных для поиска по организациям.
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search'
        }
    });
    
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
    
    // Программно выполним поиск определённых кафе в текущей
    // прямоугольной области карты.
    searchControl.search('Кафе');
    
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Answer (score 0):

Карта "соскакивает" из-за того, что происходит поиск и карта меняет центр и зум автоматически, чтобы показать его результаты.

Как это работает:

- Сначала карта создаётся и центрируется на геопозиции пользователя;
- Вызывается поиск по карте; по умолчанию он ищет объекты с приоритетом у видимой области карты, т.е. как раз около геопозиции, но не ограничен ею; к тому же, если в заданной области ничего не нашлось, она автоматически расширяется.
- Карте выставляется bounds по найденным результатам поиска.

Если вам нужно ограничивать поиск только небольшой зоной вокруг точки местоположения, нужно вычислять её самостоятельно и явно задавать опции `boundedBy` и `strictBounds` [поисковой строки](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/?from=SO). В этом случае поиск будет только в той области, которую вы задали.

P.S. в вашем коде поисковая строка добавляется дважды - первый раз при создании карты из дефолтного набора элементов управления (т.к. при создании карты не задан `controls`), а второй раз уже вами через `myMap.controls.add(searchControl)`.